# Windows UEFI dual boot Ubuntu, HELP?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb, windows

So as usual I would like to dual boot windows with Ubuntu. I read many articles and am very confused.

I created a bootable USB using Ubuntu 16.04 and pendrive linux, however

1. With fastboot OFF and in UEFI boot option,I can either read from "Windows boot manager" or "IPv4 net connection" . (So, no option to boot from USB)
2. If I go to legacy boot mode, there is an option to boot from USB.

**NOW**, the question.

I read that installing Ubuntu from legacy mode WILL NOT allow ubuntu to run alonside windows. One has to go to boot options and switch the mode (Legacy for ubuntu and UEFI for windows).
That is not what I want.

I want it to dual boot.
How can I even do that if UEFI does not show an option to boot from USB??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sure that when you have created the bootable usb drive you have selected UEFI option? If not you can use Rufus (that unfortunately works only on Windows) to create your bootable usb drive with Ubuntu 16.04 iso and specify that it is a UEFI bootable drive and not the old BIOS bootable drive. This is the link for download rufus [Link](https://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-2.9.exe) and [this](http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-ubuntu-usb-drive-using-rufus/) is a brief tutorial to use Rufus (remind to select to the field "Partition scheme and target system type" to UEFI and not BIOS)

PS If you create the usb bootable drive with non-UEFI mode the pendrive will work only in legacy.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem when trying to set up dual booting. Pendrive configures the install onto the flash drive in such a way that UEFI booting doesn't seem to work. Using another tool, such as [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie), should do the trick.